# How to resolve the situation with n if and n || in C?

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

I'm learning C programming language and I try to resolve a situation where temp could be from 1 to n and I can't use n if statements, and I don't know how to do that with a for or a while.

```
for (i=0;i<(count-1);i++) {
        if (flag == false) {
                if (temp == 1) {
                        if (i == (count - 2)) {
                                printf("%s", s1);
                        } else {
                                printf("%s",s2);
                        } 
                }

                if (temp == 2) {
                        if (i == (count - 3) || i == (count - 2)) {
                                printf("%s", s1);
                        } else {
                                printf("%s",s2);
                        } 
                }

                if (temp == 3) {
                        if (i == (count - 4) || i == (count - 3) || i == (count - 2)) {
                                printf("%s", s1);
                        } else {
                                printf("%s",s2);
                        } 
                }

                ...

                if (temp == n) {
                        if (i == (count - n+1) || i == (count - n) || ... || i == (count - 2)) {
                                printf("%s", s1);
                        } else {
                                printf("%s",s2);
                        } 
                }

        } else {
                printf("%s",s2);
        }
}
```

So temp could be from 1 to n, and temp is always smaller than count. temp couldn't be 0 because in this situation flag is true.

How can I make this code to use a for or a while? Thank you!

Comment: You need to check that `i` is between `count - 1 - temp` and `count - 2` inclusively, and you only need to check it once.

Answer (score 0):

You are lacking any information about when and to which values `temp` is set so I cannot tell how you plan to integrate that into a loop. What you certainly *can* do, though, is replacing all those `if`s (side note: a  `switch` block would have been preferable anyway) by more suitable comparisons for an entire range:

```
if(count - temp - 1 <= i && i <= count - 2)
```

Assuming temp being integral here...